# After Lucene search, get character offsets of all matched words in document? (not just preview snippet)

Tags: lucene, highlight

I am creating a search engine for a large number of HTML documents using lucene.

I know I can use `PostingsHighlighter` and friends to show snippets, with bold words, similar to Google Search results, also similar to [this random lucene-based example](http://search.carrot2.org/stable/search?source=pubmed&view=folders&skin=fancy-compact&query=data+mining&results=100&algorithm=lingo).

However, unlike these examples, I need a solution that preserves highlighted words, even after the matched document is opened by the user, similar to Google Books.

Some words are hyphenated, in the form `<div> ... an inter-</div><div...>national audience ...</div>` I am thinking I need to convert these to plain text first, and write some code to merge words that were hyphenated, before I send them to lucene.

Once the resulting document is opened by the user, I'm hoping that I can use lucene to get character offsets of each matched word in the document.

I will have to cross-reference the offsets in the plain text back to the original HTML, and write code to highlight `<b>` the words based on said offsets.

`<div> ... an <b>inter-</b></div><div...><b>national</b> audience ...</div>`

How can I get what I need from lucene? Surely I don't have to write my own search for this 'final inch'?

Comment: Just a comment because I'm not sure it's the best solution for you case, but if you go the plain text way, you can use the `Highlighter` class along with a custom implementation of an `Encoder` (just a no-op that returns the input string), and a `Formatter` which just collects the offsets of matching tokens and returns an empty string. Use the base `QueryScorer`. Works for me but I only work with plain text. There may be a better approach involving custom analyzers that would handle hyphenation over block tags.

Comment: I can fool lucene into thinking it's just searching plain text documents, as long as I can get it to provide highlights for the entire document, and not just the relevant snippet. I wish I could find an example I could run that does such highlighting of the entire document.

Comment: You can use the `NullFragmenter` to highlight in the entire document.

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer I've been looking for. I'm going to try a to implement now. Starting with [Lucene in 5 minutes](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html), and then I'll expand from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured out something I can get started with. :)

To index:

```
StandardAnalyzer analyzer - new StandardAnalyzer()
Directory index = FSDirectory.open(new File("...").toPath());
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
addDoc(writer, "...", "...");
addDoc(writer, "...", "...");
addDoc(writer, "...", "...");
// documents need to be read from the data source..
// only add once, or else your docs will be duplicated as you continue to use the system
writer.close();
```

specify offsets to store for highlighting

```
private static final FieldType typeOffsets;
static {
    typeOffsets = new FieldType(textField.TYPE_STORED);
    typeOffsets.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS_AND_OFFSETS);
}
```

method addDoc

```
void addDoc(IndexWriter writer, String title, String body) {
  Document doc = new Document();
  doc.add(new Field("title", body, typeOffsets));
  doc.add(new Field("body", body, typeOffsets));
  // you can also add an store a TextField that does not have offsets,
  // like a file ID that you wouldn't search on, just need to reference original doc.
  writer.addDocument(doc);
}
```

Perform your first search

```
String q = "...";
String[] fields = new String[] {"title", "body"};
QueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(fields, analyzer)
Query query = parser.parse(q)
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(DirectoryReader.open(index));
PostingsHighlighter highlighter = new PostingsHighlighter();
TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(query, 10, Sort.RELEVANCE);
```

Get highlighted snippets with `highlighter.highlightFields(fields, query, searcher, topDocs)`. You can iterate over the results.

When you want to highlight the end document (i.e. after the search is completed and user selected the result), use [this solution](https://dataworks-inc.com/107/) (needs minor edits). It works by using `NullFragmenter` to turn the whole thing into one snippet.

```
public static String highlight(String pText, String pQuery) throws Exception
{
    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30);
    QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "", analyzer);
    Highlighter highlighter = new Highlighter(new QueryScorer(parser.parse(pQuery)));
    highlighter.setTextFragmenter(new NullFragmenter());

    String text = highlighter.getBestFragment(analyzer, "", pText);

    if (text != null)
    {
        return text;
    }
    return pText;    
}
```

Edit: You can actually use `PostingsHighlighter` for this last step instead of `Highlighter`, but you have to override `getBreakIterator`, and then override your `BreakIterator` so that it thinks the whole document is one sentance.

Edit: You can override `getFormatter` to capture the offsets, rather than trying to parse the `<b>` tags normally output by `PostingsHighlighter`.